# Prepared statement pymysql who is correct?

Tags: python, mysql, security, pymysql

I have created a test database called test inside it has a table called testTable with an autoincrement id value and a name field that takes a varchar(30).

The PREPARE statement queries (4 of them) execute fine when copied into phpmyadmin but I get the error  2021-01-08 18:26:53,022 (MainThread) [ERROR] (1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SET\n @name = 'fred';\nEXECUTE\n statement USING @name;\nDEALLOCATE\nPREPARE\n ' at line 5")

The test code:

```
import pymysql
import logging


class TestClass():

    def __init__(self):
        # mysqlconnections

        self.mySQLHostName = "localhost" 
        self.mySQLHostPort = 3306
        self.mySQLuserName = "userName"
        self.mySQLpassword = "pass"
        self.MySQLauthchandb = "mysql"
        
    def QueryMYSQL (self, query):
        try:
            #logging.info("QueryMYSQL  : " + str( query)) # Uncomment to print all mysql queries sent
            conn = pymysql.connect(host=self.mySQLHostName, port=self.mySQLHostPort, user=self.mySQLuserName, passwd=self.mySQLpassword, db=self.MySQLauthchandb, charset='utf8')
            conn.autocommit(True)
            cursor = conn.cursor()
            if cursor:
                returnSuccess = cursor.execute(query)
                
            if cursor:
                returnValue = cursor.fetchall()
            #logging.info ("return value : " + str(returnValue)) # Uncomment to print all returned mysql queries
            if cursor:
                cursor.close()
            if conn:
                conn.close()
            return returnValue
        except Exception as e:
            logging.error("Problem in ConnectTomySQL")
            logging.error(query)
            logging.error(e)
            return False

# Default error logging log file location:
logging.basicConfig(format='%(asctime)s (%(threadName)-10s) [%(levelname)s] %(message)s', filename= 'ERROR.log',filemode = "w", level=logging.DEBUG)
logging.info("Logging Started")

test = TestClass()
result = test.QueryMYSQL("Describe test.testTable")
print(result)
query = """
PREPARE
    statement
FROM
    'INSERT INTO test.testTable (id, name) VALUES (NULL , ?)';
SET
    @name = 'fred';
EXECUTE
    statement USING @name;
DEALLOCATE
PREPARE
    statement;
    """
result = test.QueryMYSQL(query)
print(result)
```

I'm assuming this is a library issue rather than a mysql issue? I am trying to use prepared statements to prevent code injection from user input as I understand this prepared statements are the best way to do this rather than trying to pre filter user input and missing something.

I asked this question on the github but one of the authors (methane Inada Naoki) replied with this:

========

Multistatement can be used by attacker when there is a query injection vulnerability. So it is disabled by default.

```
as I understand this prepared statements are the best way
```

You are totally wrong. Your use of prepared statement doesn't protect you from SQL injection at all. If you enable multistatement, your "prepared statement" can be attacked by SQL injection.

But I am not free tech support nor free teacher for you. OSS maintainers are not. Please don't ask here.

and he closed the issue.

Is he correct?

The author book I am reading Robin Nixon,"Learning PHP, MySQL and JavaScript" O'Reilly 5th edition. He appears to be under the misconception and I quote "Let me introduce the best and recommended way to interact with MySQL, which is pretty much bulletproof in terms of Security" Its in the Using Placeholders section pg 260. Is he wrong?

Because I bought this book to improve my security practices and now I'm not sure what is correct.

Comment: This might be alluding to prepared statement emulation, but I'm not familiar with the internals of the Python driver in question. If you're using placeholder values at the driver level, without emulation, you should be fine. If there's emulation involved, there could be bugs or limitations in that implementation.

Comment: I think the issue here is you're not specifying `DELIMITER` which is causing issues. I don't trust this MySQL code at all. You're connecting and running a single statement. This is hugely inefficient and won't scale beyond even the most trivial of use cases.

Answer (score 1):

I found out from the developer of pymysql that the library does not support the PREPARE mysql statement. Also the pymysql library by default does not execute multi-statements.

I understand that my first attempt at substituting values into the INSERT statement is inherently unsafe if multi-statements are enabled. This can be done by using the client_flag=pymysql.constants.CLIENT.MULTI_STATEMENTS in the connect constructor.

The pymysql library does however allow for placeholders to be used in MySQL queries using the cursor.execute(query, (tuple)) method.

To demonstrate this I wrote the following test code example.

```
import pymysql
import logging

class TestClass():

    def __init__(self):
        # mysqlconnections

        self.mySQLHostName = "localhost"
        self.mySQLHostPort = 3306
        self.mySQLuserName = "name"
        self.mySQLpassword = "pw"
        self.MySQLauthchandb = "mysql"
        
    def QueryMYSQL (self, query, data = ()):
        try:
            logging.info("QueryMYSQL  : " + str( query)) # Uncomment to print all mysql queries sent
            conn = pymysql.connect(host=self.mySQLHostName, port=self.mySQLHostPort, user=self.mySQLuserName, passwd=self.mySQLpassword, db=self.MySQLauthchandb, charset='utf8', client_flag=pymysql.constants.CLIENT.MULTI_STATEMENTS) #code injection requires multistatements to be allowed this is off in pymysql by default and has to be set on manually. 
            conn.autocommit(True)
            cursor = conn.cursor()
            if cursor:
                if data:
                    returnSuccess = cursor.execute(query, data)
                else:
                    returnSuccess = cursor.execute(query)
                
            if cursor:
                returnValue = cursor.fetchall()
            logging.info ("return value : " + str(returnValue)) # Uncomment to print all returned mysql queries
            if cursor:
                cursor.close()
            if conn:
                conn.close()
            return returnValue
        except Exception as e:
            logging.error("Problem in ConnectTomySQL")
            logging.error(e)
            logging.error(query)
            if data:
                logging.error("Data {}".format(str(data)))
            return False

# Default error logging log file location:
logging.basicConfig(format='%(asctime)s (%(threadName)-10s) [%(levelname)s] %(message)s', filename= 'ERROR.log',filemode = "w", level=logging.DEBUG)
logging.info("Logging Started")

def usePlaceholder(userInput):
    query = "INSERT INTO test.testTable (id, name) VALUES (NULL , %s)"
    data = (userInput,) 
    result = test.QueryMYSQL(query,data)
    print(result)

def useSubstitution(userInput):
    query = "INSERT INTO test.testTable (id, name) VALUES (NULL , '{}')".format(userInput) # this is unsafe.
    result = test.QueryMYSQL(query)
    print(result)

test = TestClass()

#Create the test database and testTable.
query = "CREATE DATABASE test"
test.QueryMYSQL(query)
query = "CREATE TABLE `test`.`testTable` ( `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT , `name` VARCHAR(256) NULL DEFAULT NULL , PRIMARY KEY (`id`)) ENGINE = InnoDB;"
test.QueryMYSQL(query)

#Simulated user input.
legitUserEntry = "Ringo"
injectionAttempt = "333' ); INSERT INTO test.testTable (id, name) VALUES (NULL , 666);#" #A simulated user sql injection attempt.

useSubstitution(legitUserEntry) # this will also insert Ringo - but could be unsafe.
usePlaceholder(legitUserEntry) # this will insert Ringo - but is safer.

useSubstitution(injectionAttempt) # this will inject the input code and execute it. 
usePlaceholder(injectionAttempt) # this will insert the input into the database without executing the injected code.
```

So from this exercise, I shall henceforth improve my security by keeping multi-statements set to off (the default) AND using the placeholders and data tuple rather than substitution.

Comment: Yes, there's no advantage to using multi-query, and when multi-query is in effect, true prepared statements are not supported. Just keep it simple: one SQL statement per call, and use parameters.